# UWP gridview item selection style

Tags: gridview, selection, win-universal-app

I want to change the selection style or color of the gridview item. when an item is selected, I want to show a thicker border or a highlight color or any type of change like that. what is the simplest way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example:

I have my page like this:

```
<Page x:Class="App3.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="using:App3"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="MyList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
                    <TextBlock Text="Test1" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I fill my list:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        MyList.SelectionChanged += MyList_SelectionChanged;
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("1");
        list.Add("2");
        MyList.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

Finally I get the selected item and I change the background

```
 private void MyList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       var item= MyList.ContainerFromItem(e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault());
        var selectedItem = item as ListViewItem;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            var grid = selectedItem.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

        }


    }
```

If you see I use ContentTemplateRoot with this property I have access to the principal container of my ItemTemplate.

[image]

Please mark this answer If it's useful for you!

Comment: Normally this is done in `XAML` not code behind

Comment: Well Triggers is not supported in UWP apps like SL or WPF for UWP there are only AdaptiveTriggers and DataStateTrigger

Comment: They are supported just inherit from `StateTriggerBase` to create desired behaviour. Some really useful state triggers can be found in the [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers)

Comment: @swilko , yes can you please tell me how to do this in xaml ?

Comment: yes I want to know that

Comment: I agree with @SWilko here. You're putting unnecessary, bug-prone logic in your code behind. My answer here should work better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705335/uwp-win10-listview-selecteditem-style/35705551#35705551 You are not accounting for the item you just deselected, or a possibility of an item being selected when you first started or the fact that item containers may be reused as you scroll a virtualized list etc.

Comment: @MuhammadTouseef triggers are unnecessary here have a look at Filip's answer for best way to do this