# uwp win10 Listview SelectedItem Style

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

Is there a way to change the properties of a  ListviewItem when this one is selected?

As an example, I want that a rectangle inside the ListviewItem to be Red when selected and Blue by default.

How to achieve this in an elegant manner?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` to customize the style of `ListViewItems` used in the `ListView`.

This page shows the default style: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx

In case of your example - you would change the `Selected~Background` properties in code similar to below:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <ListViewItemPresenter
          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
          SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
          CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
          FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
          FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
          PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
          PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
          SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
          PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
          SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
          DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
          DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
          ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
          ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CheckMode="Inline"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Also,how to change BorderBrush for SelectedItem using this style?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this later, I have resolved this with a library in Nuget: https://github.com/JerryNixon/Template10.ListHelpers

It's behavior uses separate styles for each state.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemNormalStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Dark" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ItemSelectedStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Light" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Using it is pretty simplistic, too. It's an attached property.

```
<ListView 
    helpers:ListViewHelper.SelectedItemStyle="{StaticResource MySelectorInfo}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

// best of luck

Answer (score -1):

I have already answered this question in another place please check it!
[UWP gridview item selection style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703823/uwp-gridview-item-selection-style)

Comment: Well, that may certainly work, I just like my answer more and wouldn't recommend yours. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Filip. I already had the xaml prepared the way you presented it. Ricardo's code just pushed me 1 step further to solve the problem. I voted both answers, but I have chosen his. Thanks again to both of you.