# UWP list view cell separator

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

as stated in title, I'm trying to get cell separator for `ListView`. and i found a way to draw the separator but unfortunately it causes list view items to not have cell hover color and cell selection color.

```
<Style x:Key="BorderedItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="4,0,4,0">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

I also tried [this style solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705551) to add the highlight/selection color back. but the issue is `ListViewItemPresenter` cannot be inside a `Border`. putting a `Border` inside `ListViewItemPresenter` hides the whole cell. so there anyway to have cell separator without losing highlight/hover/selection color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setting the style for the `ListViewItem`, don't forget the `VisualStateGroups` setting which is for controlling highlight, hover, selection and other effects. Also you don't need to add a border control for cell separator. Just set `BorderBrush` for the `ContentPresenterGrid` it will work well. Updated style as follows:

```
 <Style x:Key="BorderedItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                 <Grid
                     x:Name="ContentBorder"
                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                     <Rectangle
                         x:Name="BorderBackground"
                         Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                         Opacity="0"
                         Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                     <Grid
                         x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid"
                         Margin="0,0,0,0"
                         Background="Transparent"
                         BorderBrush="LightGray"
                         BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                         <Grid.RenderTransform>
                             <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                         </Grid.RenderTransform>
                         <ContentPresenter
                             x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                             Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                             VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                             Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                             ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                             ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                     </Grid>
                     <!--
                         The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                         In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                         approximate the size of the item using placeholder text.
                     -->
                     <TextBlock
                         x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                         Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                         Foreground="{x:Null}"
                         Opacity="0"
                         AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False"
                         Text="Xg" />
                     <Rectangle
                         x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                         Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                         Visibility="Collapsed" />
                     <Rectangle
                         x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                         Opacity="0"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                     <Border
                         x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
                         Width="20"
                         Height="20"
                         Margin="12,0,0,0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                         BorderThickness="2"
                         Visibility="Collapsed">
                         <Border.Clip>
                             <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20">
                                 <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                     <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectClipTransform" />
                                 </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                             </RectangleGeometry>
                         </Border.Clip>
                         <Border.RenderTransform>
                             <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform" />
                         </Border.RenderTransform>
                         <FontIcon
                             x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                             Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                             Opacity="0"
                             FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                             FontSize="16"
                             Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                             Visibility="Collapsed" />
                     </Border>
                     <TextBlock
                         x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Margin="18,9,0,0"
                         Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                         Opacity="0"
                         FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                         FontSize="26.667"
                         AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False"
                         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                         TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0:0:0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0:0:0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0:0:0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />
                             <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectDisabled">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
                                         <SplineDoubleKeyFrame
                                             KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.333"
                                             Value="-32" />
                                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectClipTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
                                         <SplineDoubleKeyFrame
                                             KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.333"
                                             Value="32" />
                                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="32" />
                                         <SplineDoubleKeyFrame
                                             KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.333"
                                             Value="0" />
                                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="Collapsed" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectEnabled">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-32" />
                                         <SplineDoubleKeyFrame
                                             KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.333"
                                             Value="0" />
                                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectClipTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="32" />
                                         <SplineDoubleKeyFrame
                                             KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.333"
                                             Value="0" />
                                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                         <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-32" />
                                         <SplineDoubleKeyFrame
                                             KeySpline="0.1,0.9,0.2,1"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.333"
                                             Value="0" />
                                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="32,0,0,0" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable" />
                             <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint" />
                             <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                         Direction="Bottom"
                                         ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                         TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                         Direction="Top"
                                         ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                         TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                         Direction="Right"
                                         ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                         TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DragOverThemeAnimation
                                         Direction="Left"
                                         ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                         TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                 <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint" />
                             </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
                             <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                     <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <!--
                                         These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
                                         on the same elements animate an internal Opacity.
                                     -->
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                                     <DoubleAnimation
                                         Duration="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                                     <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                                     <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                                     <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualState x:Name="DraggedPlaceholder">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                                 </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                             <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                 <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging" />
                             </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                 </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

And the result:

[image]

More details please reference [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx). And I have a demo about the ListView cell separator you may reference:https://github.com/sunteenwu/CDesign

Comment: first of all thank you very much for helping. that solved my problem. i tried blend to edit a default copy of item container style but it didn't contained those visual style. it would have been nice because I've never thought adding a line in the bottom of a cell would need 392 lines of (xaml) code. anyway, thanks for the linked demo i'm going to study it.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Thanks!