# UWP : How to modify shape of Selected rectangle to have rounded edges in a GridView?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I was looking to customize the selected rectangle which appears over a GridViewItem in a UWP App.

Main.xaml

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DemoImages" x:DataType="vm:DemoImages">
        <Border
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Image
                    Source="{x:Bind PathOfImage, Mode=OneWay}"  //Path of image is defines in class DemoImages as a string which takes the path to an image
                    Height="10"
                    Width="10"/>
            </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root" 
                                           CheckBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBrush}" 
                                           ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                           CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" 
                                           ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                           CheckMode="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckMode}" 
                                           DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                                           DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" 
                                           DragBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragBackground}" 
                                           DragForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragForeground}" 
                                           FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" 
                                           FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" 
                                           FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" 
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                           Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPressed}" 
                                           PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" 
                                           PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" 
                                           PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" 
                                           RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}" 
                                           ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                           RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemRevealBorderBrush}" 
                                           RevealBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemRevealBackground}" 
                                           SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundSelected}" 
                                           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource GridViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" 
                                           SelectedBackground="Black" 
                                           SelectedPressedBackground="Black" 
                                           SelectedPointerOverBackground="Black"
                                           MinHeight="10"
                                           MinWidth="10"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.()" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ListViewItemPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>



      <Grid>
        <GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemContainerStyle1}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.DemoIcons}"
            SelectionMode="single"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DemoImages}">
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

I modified the Visual state manager so that the selected rectangle appears black and has a pink backgound. How do I get a Circle instead of the rectangle here ?  I tried to Corner Radius but that makes the rectangle disappear. Also how do i change the background of my icon when I Hover or select it ? Setting property in Visual State manager seems to be giving me an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uwp win10 Listview SelectedItem Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705335/uwp-win10-listview-selecteditem-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the behavior about the selected rectangle, you could use the [GridViewItemExpanded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates#expanded-xaml-item-templates) template which included with the default styles in **generic.xaml**.

> I modified the Visual state manager so that the selected rectangle appears black and has a pink backgound.

The `GridViewItemExpanded` template and your `GridViewItemContainerStyle1` template are both `ItemContainerStyle`, they are not used at the same time. Therefore, you need to set the selected rectangle’ color again in the `GridViewItemExpanded` template.

You need to find the `VisualState` name `Selected`, `PointerOverSelected` and `PressedSelected` and change the the value of `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` property whose **Storyboard.TargetName** is `MultiSelectSquare` (`MultiSelectSquare` is the selected rectangle’s `Name`) and **Storyboard.TargetProperty** is `Background` as `Black`, like this:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

To get a pink background, you can change the value of a `Setter` whose `Property` is `Background`, like this:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
```

> How do I get a Circle instead of the rectangle here ?

You need to find the `Border` named `MultiSelectSquare` in `GridViewItemExpanded` template and add a property `CornerRadius="10"`, the value `"10"` can be adjusted based on the size of your `Border` control.

> Also how do i change the background of my icon when I Hover or select it ?

You could find the `VisualState` name `PointerOver` and `Selected` and change the value of `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` whose **Storyboard.TargetName** is `MultiSelectSquare` and **Storyboard.TargetProperty** is `Background` to your targeted color.